# how can i use inbuilt django authentication and admin panel with MongoDB ? How can i make a connection like regular SQL in settings.py for mongoDB

Tags: python, django, mongodb

connection with this settings works for CRUD methods but is incompatible for admin panel and authenticaion.if there is some way by which i can make connection with MongoDB like our regular POSTGRES,SQLITE eg with engine and port numbers in DATABASE Varibale in Settings.py file . Please Suggest

#

Settings.py

```
"""
Django settings for calculator project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 2.0.2.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/
"""

import os

DBDNAME='mydata'
_MONGODB_HOST='localhost'
_MONGODB_NAME='mydata'
_MONGODB_DATABASE_HOST = \
    'mongodb://%s:%s@%s/%s'\
    %('','',_MONGODB_HOST,_MONGODB_NAME)
# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
TEMPLATES_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates')


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '3gcc++w$zhw7k=4&)po*r4_sqc_u7vhbqt0vpdsx(&-#ob#taj'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'calc.apps.CalcConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'calculator.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [TEMPLATES_DIR],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'calculator.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': '',
        'NAME': '',
    }
}

DBNAME='mydata'
_MONGODB_USER_=''


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

#

models.py

```
from mongoengine import *
from calculator.settings import DBNAME
# Create your models here.

connect(DBNAME)

class information(Document):
    number1 = StringField(max_length=120)
    number2 = StringField(max_length=120)
    values = StringField(max_length=120)
    Result = StringField(max_length=120)
```

#

Please help me how should i proceed for admin panel and Authentication?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [django mongoengine](https://github.com/MongoEngine/django-mongoengine). This is good for basic admin CRUD applications and will quickly get your work done.